# Zebra Label Printer - Cut After Last Page of Document Not Every Page

Tags: printing, zebra-printers, zpl

I have a Zebra GX420t connected via network, I'm trying to cut after the last page of a multi-page pdf document, not after every single page.  I've inserted ZPL *Custom Commands* into the *Start* and *End* fields in the printer preferences.  I've tried several combinations including:

Start:
^XA^MMD^XZ

END:
~JK

If I watch the *print mode* field in the web interface for the printer I can see the mode change from whatever it previously was to "Delayed Cut Mode" (^MMD) so I know the ZPL commands are working. Unfortunately the ~JK command never initiates the cut.  If I send the ~JK command manually (via Tools tab in printer preferences) after the print is completed it will cut.  I notice that the ZPL manual says the ~JK command will only execute if the label has completed printing.  This leads me to believe that the ZPL contained in the *End* field is being sent immediately and this is why it's not printing?  Does anyone have some additional info on how to solve this problem?  Is there some way I can introduce some sort of delay/pause/timeout command in my ZPL to allow enough time to pass for the label printing to complete before the cut command is sent?

I have tried the solution mentioned by Chris S. here:
[Zebra Printer - Cut on last page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49394248/zebra-printer-cut-on-last-page)
It doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution.

1. Create a file with the name: **Delayed Cut Settings.txt**
2. Insert the following code: **^XA^MMC,N^XZ**
3. Send it to the printer

After you do the 3 steps above, all the documents you send to the printer will be cut automatically.

(To disable that function send again the 'Delayed Cut Setting.txt' with the following code:**^XA^MMD^XZ** )

My EXAMPLE TXT:

```
^XA

^FX Top section with logo, name and address.
^CF0,60
^FO50,50^GB100,100,100^FS
^FO75,75^FR^GB100,100,100^FS
^FO93,93^GB40,40,40^FS
^FO220,50^FDIntershipping, Inc.^FS
^CF0,30
^FO220,115^FD1000 Shipping Lane^FS
^FO220,155^FDShelbyville TN 38102^FS
^FO220,195^FDUnited States (USA)^FS
^FO50,250^GB700,3,3^FS

^FX Second section with recipient address and permit information.
^CFA,30
^FO50,300^FDJohn Doe^FS
^FO50,340^FD100 Main Street^FS
^FO50,380^FDSpringfield TN 39021^FS
^FO50,420^FDUnited States (USA)^FS
^CFA,15
^FO600,300^GB150,150,3^FS
^FO638,340^FDPermit^FS
^FO638,390^FD123456^FS
^FO50,500^GB700,3,3^FS

^FX Third section with bar code.
^BY5,2,270
^FO100,550^BC^FD12345678^FS

^FX Fourth section (the two boxes on the bottom).
^FO50,900^GB700,250,3^FS
^FO400,900^GB3,250,3^FS
^CF0,40
^FO100,960^FDCtr. X34B-1^FS
^FO100,1010^FDREF1 F00B47^FS
^FO100,1060^FDREF2 BL4H8^FS
^CF0,190
^FO470,955^FDCA^FS

^XZ
```